# Finding odd numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

Write an ARM function (subroutine) to count the number of odd integers in an integer array. The function signature is:

```
int numodd( int array[], int size ) ;
```

where:
    int array[] is passed to the ARM function as a pointer to the first element of the integer array and,
    int size is passed by value and is the number of elements in the array.

The C language source code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern int numodd( int array[], int size ) ;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int numarray[] = { 2, 3, 1025, 3024, 4057, -3, -1025, -3578 } ;
    int size = sizeof(numarray) / sizeof( int ) ;
    int result ;

    result = numodd( numarray, size ) ;
    printf( "Number of odd numbers: %d\n", result ) ;

    exit( 0 ) ;

}
```

Assembly code (so far):

```
        .global numodd
        .text
numodd: stmfd sp!,{v1-v6,lr}
        mov a3, #0
elop:   ldr a4, [a1], #4
        tst a4, #1
        beq odd
        subs a2, a2, #1
        bne elop
odd:    add a3, a3, #1
        bne elop
        mov a1, a3
        ldmfd sp!,{v1-v6,pc}
        .end
```

Comment: What is your question?  Does this code do what you expect?  See [ask].  If it doesn't, usually your best bet is to single-step through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you just forgot the extra `subs`, or if you thought ARM had branch delay slots, but you're only decrementing `a2` in the "even" case.

Note that `beq odd` is unnecessary since you could use conditional execution instead, which will be more efficient:

```
    tst a4, #1
    addne a3, a3, #1      @ if (a4 & 1) a3++ 
    subs a2, a2, #1
    bne elop
    mov a1, a3
    ldmfd sp!,{v1-v6,pc}
```

Comment: @Micheal - which ARM version is this?

Comment: @InfinitelyManic: It's pre-unified syntax if that's what you're asking. I just followed whatever syntax the OP was using (looks like armasm, for ARMv4 or possibly something even older).

Comment: Thanks man. It worked perfectly. I'll have to read up on that to get a better understanding for next time.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference an ARMv8 macro to prime the pump.

```
// isOdd
.macro isOdd num
.isOdd\@:
push2 x1, xzr
        mov x1, \num
        ands x0, x1, 1          // if result is True then subject bit is set
        cset x0, ne             // ne = Z flag not set; 1 AND 1 == 1 so clears Z flag; so set x0 to 0 if even num
pop2 x1, xzr
.endm
```